# Delphi 6. How do I read pdf data back from MS Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, pdf

I managed to save the pdf file to an MS Access db as follows. But I have no idea how to read it back and save as a file

```
procedure TForm1.btnTask3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SL, splitString: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  sourceFile,
  sourceFile1,
  outputFile : string;
  firstName,
  lastName,
  userId  : string;
  dateOfBirth  : TDate;
  dbConnectionStrPath : string;
begin
  //set database connection string
  dbConnectionStrPath := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
            'Data Source='+GetCurrentDir+'\task3.mdb;'+
            'Persist Security Info=False';

  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //Assign input and output paths
    sourceFile := GetCurrentDir + '\source.txt';
    sourceFile1 := 'C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\nb\shortcuts.pdf';
    outputFile := GetCurrentDir + '\output.txt';

    //Load the file into the stringlist
    SL.LoadFromFile(sourcefile);
    // For holding indivisual lines
    splitString := TStringList.Create;

    //Database stuff
    //Set the connection string, table to save to and activate
    ADOTable.ConnectionString := dbConnectionStrPath;
    ADOTable.TableName := 'Patient';
    ADOTable.Active := True;

    splitString.Delimiter := ',';
    for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    begin

      // Split the line by the comma
      splitString.DelimitedText := SL[i];

      //Assign each comma separeted value to a variable
      firstName   := splitString[0];
      lastName    := splitString[1];
      userId      := splitString[2];
      dateOfBirth := StrToDate(splitString[3]);

      //Assign values to the database table
      ADOTable.Append;
      ADOTable['UserId']    := userId;
      ADOTable['firstname'] := firstName;
      ADOTable['lastname']  := lastName;
      ADOTable['DOB']       := dateOfBirth;
      //Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974259/access-2007-add-file-as-attachment-with-delphi
      TBlobField(ADOTable.FieldByName('File')).LoadFromFile(sourceFile1);

      //Save the data
      ADOTable.Post;

    end;
    splitString.Free;

    ShowMessage('Data saved to database');
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you seem to have figured out storing a file in a Blob field ok, so I'm not entirely sure what (conceptual) problem you are having with extracting the file again, because you are 90% of the way there already.

Read the Online Help for

`TBlobField.SaveToFile()`

Obviously, before you can use that routine, you need to navigate your `AdoTable` to the record containing the Blob you want to extract.  You could do something like

```
if AdoTable.Locate('LastName;FirstName', VarArrayOf(['Doe', 'John']), []) then begin
  // Save your blob to disk here.
end;
```

That is what you should try.  Then ask a new q if/when you get stuck.

Btw, what has the PDF tag to do with your q?  Your code operates on text files.

Comment: Did this answer your q or are you still stuck?